# Div is not getting in front of previous div Issues in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

well I am facing Problem that the extender list show behind the pop up , I have tried so many css but after googling I found there is css bug in chrome while in IE and Firefox its work fine. please  Help me out.

This Is the snapshot of Chrome

[image: This Is the Problem In Chrome]

Now This Is the Snap Shot of IE and FireFox

[image: Woriking Fine in IE and FireFox]

I Removed all Css for Extender'sTextbox

Now its look like

```
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="727px"></asp:TextBox>
    <Syed:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCountry"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" >
</Syed:AutoCompleteExtender>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 



    <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: You mentioned that you tried some CSS.  Did you making sure your extender list parent div has the correct level of z-index?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Z-index of the div

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

To be sure that this will solve the problem just add an inline style like this to the div:

```
<div ... style="z-index: 1000;"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Not working <div ... style="z-index: 1000;"> ... </div>

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.
Adding browser compatibility just below the head tag.it can work

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9, IE=8, IE=7" />
```

Comment: Not working this also <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9, IE=8, IE=7" /> and by the I faceing issue in chrome not in IE